# IE9でローカルのファイルを読み込むことは可能ですか？

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

やりたいことは下記のようにファイル名をinput要素で指定してもらい、ボタンを押したらその内容を取得したいです。
csvファイルを読み込むことを想定しています。
IE10以降ではFileAPIが使えるのですが、IE9では動きません。

下記のように書けばできるかと思いましたが、このコードは動きませんでした。

すいません、制約を書いてませんでした。
ActiveXなどのMS独自の制約機能は使いたくないです。
ただし、JQueryなどメジャーなライブラリで差を吸収してくれるものであれば使用しても良いと思っています。

```
<html>
<head>
<title>サンプル</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CSVTEST() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("csvfile").value;
        alert(elem);

        $.get(elem, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    };
</script>

<input id="csvfile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="CSVTEST()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IEではデータバインドという形でローカルファイルをHTMLに関連付けて読み込むことが可能です。CSVデータならtableに割り付けるといいかと思います。ググれば例は色々と見つかると思います。[参考](http://www.openspc2.org/reibun/javascript/table/010/)

Comment: あと、HTAアプリケーションにしてしまうのもありかと思います。

Comment: jsファイルのデータとしてファイルの中身を埋め込んでおけば（例：`var text = "data1,data2,data3";`） `$.getScript` で読込できます。

Answer (score 0):

1. WebSocketサーバーを実装したネイティブアプリをユーザーが起動する
2. Webアプリをブラウザで開き、ローカルホスト上のWebSocketサーバーと接続を行う。
3. Webアプリからブラウザを通じて命令を送信し、ネイティブアプリを操作する。

詳細は以下を参照してください。
https://qiita.com/tekka/items/1bf440ccd50bb4171886